# Do non-type template parameters exist in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, singleton-type

Is it possible to have value generics in scala?
That is, generics which are not a type but a value.
I would imagine them to look something like this: `class Animal[legs: Int]`, but it does not compile.

I have managed to get this to compile but I am not sure the compiler understands it the same way that I do.

```scala
abstract sealed class WheeledVehicle(wheels: Int)
case object Motorcycle extends WheeledVehicle(2)
case object Atv extends WheeledVehicle(4)
case object Car extends WheeledVehicle(4)
case object Truck extends WheeledVehicle(6)
```

Further more, I have not been able to match on a `vehicle` value.

```scala
vehicle match {
    case _: WheeledVehicle(2) => useTwoWheels()
    case _: WheeledVehicle(4) => useFourWheels()
    case _: WheeledVehicle(6) => useSixWheels()
}
```

Value generics exists in some other languages, such as C++.
But what about in scala?
And if they do not, is there another way to do what I would like to do?

Comment: I would like to add more vehicles, but for this match I only care about how many wheels the vehicles have.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are talking about. I have never heard the term "value generics" before. I am not familiar with C++, which you say has value generics, so that might be the reason I don't recognize the term. However, I wasn't able to find *any* mention of "value generics" in the ISO C++ Specification, nor in any C++ book, or on [so], or a single hit on Google. Given that this doesn't seem to be a widely-recognized term, it might help if you provide a precise definition of what semantics you believe value generics should have.

Comment: Especially since none of your examples have anything to do with generics, nor does the existing, upvoted, answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you just want to define custom `unapply`

```
abstract sealed class WheeledVehicle(val wheels: Int)
object WheeledVehicle {
  def unapply(arg: WheeledVehicle): Option[Int] = Some(arg.wheels)
}

vehicle match {
  case WheeledVehicle(2) => useTwoWheels()
  case WheeledVehicle(4) => useFourWheels()
  case WheeledVehicle(6) => useSixWheels()
}
```

`Motorcycle` will match the first pattern, `Atv` and `Car` will match the second, `Truck` will match the third.

Or

```
abstract sealed class WheeledVehicle(val wheels: Int)

vehicle match {
  case w: WheeledVehicle if w.wheels == 2 => useTwoWheels()
  case w: WheeledVehicle if w.wheels == 4 => useFourWheels()
  case w: WheeledVehicle if w.wheels == 6 => useSixWheels()
}
```

or

```
vehicle match {
  case _ if vehicle.wheels == 2 => useTwoWheels()
  case _ if vehicle.wheels == 4 => useFourWheels()
  case _ if vehicle.wheels == 6 => useSixWheels()
}
```

or

```
if (vehicle.wheels == 2) useTwoWheels()
else if (vehicle.wheels == 4) useFourWheels()
else if (vehicle.wheels == 6) useSixWheels()
else useDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by value generics in C++ you mean [non-type template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter), Scala doesn't support them directly but can do some of the same things with singleton types, especially [in Scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html):

```
class Animal[Legs <: Int with Singleton]

val x = new Animal[10]
```

or if you need access to the value

```
class Animal[Legs <: Int with Singleton](implicit v: ValueOf[Legs]) {
  def legs = v.value
}

val x = new Animal[10]
println(x.legs)
```

You can't pattern-match on `Animal[10]` vs `Animal[4]`, but then you can't do it for `List[String]` vs `List[Int]` either. What you can do is pass on the parameter, e.g.:

```
def f[N <: Int with Singleton](vehicle: WheeledVehicle[N]) = useNWheels[N]()

def useNWheels[N <: Int with Singleton]() = ...
```